# Color of link within H1 tag doesn't change why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a link within the h1 tag. Html code as follows:

```
    <h1 class="redheadline">
    <a href="">Link text color here..</a> 
    </h1>
```

The css code I'm trying to use is:

```
h1.redheadline {font-size: 1.75rem; color:red;}
```

The font size changes but the color of the link's text doesn't change. Where in the css code I have to add color? Thanks!

Comment: The class names in the css and html tag `h1` are different. Try `h1.redheadline{font-size: 1.75rem; color:red;}`

Comment: class name in html and css file arn't the same

Comment: My sincere apologies I fixed the html code. But it won't work.. the color doesn't change. Do I have to add "a" to the css?

Comment: Open your page in a browser and right click on it and select "View Inspector" or "Inspect Element" and there is a whole suite of tools in most modern browsers to tell you exactly what CSS is applied to which elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `h1.headline` and `<h1 class="redheadline">` they are not the same class name.
2. Since its `<a>` element has a default color, it does not accept a color from its parent.

**Chrome defaults:**

[image]

To do this is to define the correct classes to override the default attributes of the element.

Returning to your question, we should define as `h1.redheadline a { ... }`.

**You can run the code snippet.**

```css
h1.redheadline {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

h1.redheadline a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="redheadline">
  <a href="">Link text color here..</a>
</h1>
```

**For your second question:**

```css
h1.redheadline a {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="redheadline">
  <a href="">Link text color here..</a> Pure Heading Text Here...
</h1>
```

Comment: I can write css code as h1.redheadline a {font-size:1.75rem; color:red;} ?

Comment: @falcon356 yes, it is also right. But if you write text other than the <a> element. This time the text appears as the default size of h1. I'm adding an example for your question to the snippet.

Comment: Btw u saying h1.redheadline a {.....} will make changes to other <a> tags too?

Comment: Actually no. If there is only text inside the `<h1>` tag but outside the `<a>` tag, then the text will appear in the default size of `<h1>`.

Answer (score 2):

The class name that you have given to `h1` tag in `html` code is `redheadline`, but you are trying to apply the style on `h1.headline`. Hence it is not applying the style correctly.

You need to use the correct classname.

```
h1.redheadline{font-size: 1.75rem; color:red;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your css classname does not match 'redheadline'.